# finding equation of non linear curve using it's area?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves

Is there a way to find the equation of a nonlinear curve using its area and one know coordinate? I was doing some research and I couldn't find the answer to it.

Comment: You should add more infos about the specific problem you have in mind

Comment: I think if we have area of the equation in terms of variable x coordinate then we can use Newton-Leibniz formula for finding the curve equation